# Sorting nodes in treeview

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I've the following class

```
public class TreeViewNode : NotificationObject
{
  public TreeViewNode()
  {
    Children = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewNode >();
  }
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (_name == value) return;
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Name);
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<FolderJobTreeViewNode> _children;
    public ObservableCollection<FolderJobTreeViewNode> Children
    {
        get { return _children; }
        set
        {

            if (_children == value) return;
              _children = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Children);
        }
    }

    private TreeViewNode _parent;
    public TreeViewNode Parent
    {
        get { return _parent; }
        set
        {
            if (_parent == value) return;
            _parent = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Parent);
        }
    }

}
```

and in XAML file I binded the TreeView ItemSource to collection of TreeViewNode

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="0"
                  x:Name="FoldersAndJobsTree"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding TreeViewNodeCollection}"/>
```

My request is to sorting all the node including the child nodes.
I success to sort just the roots .. I think to sort the collection before the displaying of the nodes in the tree, but it's not what I looking for

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to be able to sort dynamically, or are you just trying to sort things, say, alphabetically before the tree is rendered?

Comment: I need to sort it dynamically

Comment: How do you change the sort order?  Is it a button?  Combo box?  Or do you do it automatically in code?